# regex command(remove everything but specified txt)

Tags: java, regex

Does anyone out there know of a regex command that will take the following string

```
 url = http://184.154.145.114:8013/wlraac name = wlr  samplerate = 44100 channels = 2       format = S16le
```

and remove everything but the following

```
 wlr
```

This line will come up multiple times, where everything changes after the = sign and each time all I want to keep is whats after name =

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
.*name =\s*(\w+).*
```

and replace with the content of  group 1

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30lco)

I search for "name =" and anything before. The `\s*` matches the following whitespace.

Then the `\w+` inside brackets. `\w` will match any character and digit and underscore (if you use the option `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` otherwise it sticks to ASCII only) . Because of the brackets it is stored in the first group.

```
String in = " url = http://184.154.145.114:8013/wlraac name = wlr  samplerate = 44100 channels = 2       format = S16le";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(".*name =\\s*(\\w+).*");
Matcher m = r.matcher(in);

String result = m.replaceAll("$1");
System.out.println(result);
```

Or your code

```
String str = line2.replaceAll(".*name =\\S*(\\W).*", "$1");
```

Comment: When I change this .*name =\s*(\w+).* to this .*name =\\s*(\\w+).* it is nearly correct

Comment: Yes Java needs double escaping. Why is it only nearly correct? Whats wrong?

Comment: because it gets rid of everything completely even the wlr

Comment: Have you replaced with the content of capturing group 1? It would be easier if you showed some code.

Comment: String str = line2.replaceAll(".*name =\\S*(\\W).*", ""); this is wat im using in the code to do it

Comment: You need to replace with group 1 not with the empty string. I updated my answer with code.

Comment: Thanks very much that was a great help

Answer (score 0):

From your description its a little bit hard to understand what you need.
But regex is overkill. You should use smth like:

```
String s = myString.substring(myString.indexOf("name =")+6);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to *extract* the word that appears after `=`, i.e.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("=\\s*(\\S+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    String value = m.group(1); // contains your wlr
    ...............
}
```